# How to remove duplicate in List<T> JAVA 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8

Practically I know ways to reduce duplicate trought `distinct()`, or assign `List` to `Set`, but I have a little different issue. 
How to solve smart way below problem in JAVA 8 using stream or may be `StreamEx` ?

Let's say we have a objects in List

`A, A, A, B, B, A, A, A, C, C, C, A, A, B, B, A`

Now I need

`A, B, A, C, A, B, A`

So duplicated was removed but only if appear as next, but should stay if next to then is different object. 
I tried a few solutions but ware ugly, and not readable.

Comment: I may be wrong but streams may not be best tool since you need to store somewhere state which will inform us about previous value and if I remember correctly streams preferred to be stateless. Why not use simple loop?

Comment: You can do it with a stateful filter, but you shouldn't do that, because it'll fail if the stream is parallel.

Comment: Your best option is likely to create your own `Collector`, so the duplicates can be removed as they are added to the result `List`. A better option is to not use streams.

Comment: This really sounds like a hammer-nail problem. Use a `Set` and be done with it. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Option 1: Filter

You *could* write a stateful filter, but you **should never do that**, because it *violates* the contract of [`filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-):

> `predicate` - a [non-interfering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference), [**stateless**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) predicate to apply to each element to determine if it should be included

```
public class NoRepeatFilter<T> implements Predicate<T> {
    private T prevValue;
    @Override
    public boolean test(T value) {
        if (value.equals(this.prevValue))
            return false;
        this.prevValue = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
List<String> result = Stream
        .of("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A")
//      .parallel()
        .filter(new NoRepeatFilter<>())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

*Output*

`[A, B, A, C, A, B, A]`

The reason it must be stateless is that it'll fail if the stream is parallel, e.g. running test again with `.parallel()` uncommented:

`[A, A, B, B, A, C, C, C, A, B, B, A]`

---

#### Option 2: Collector

A valid solution is to create your own [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) using [`of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-):

```
public class NoRepeatCollector {
    public static <E> Collector<E, ?, List<E>> get() {
        return Collector.of(ArrayList::new,
                            NoRepeatCollector::addNoRepeat,
                            NoRepeatCollector::combineNoRepeat);
    }
    private static <E> void addNoRepeat(List<E> list, E value) {
        if (list.isEmpty() || ! list.get(list.size() - 1).equals(value))
            list.add(value);
    }
    private static <E> List<E> combineNoRepeat(List<E> left, List<E> right) {
        if (left.isEmpty())
            return right;
        if (! right.isEmpty())
            left.addAll(left.get(left.size() - 1).equals(right.get(0))
                        ? right.subList(1, right.size()) : right);
        return left;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
List<String> result = Stream
        .of("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A")
//      .parallel()
        .collect(NoRepeatCollector.get());
System.out.println(result);
```

*Output (with and without `.parallel()`)*

`[A, B, A, C, A, B, A]`

---

#### Option 3: Loop

If your input is a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (or other [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)), you could remove repeating values using a simple loop:

```
public static <E> void removeRepeats(Iterable<E> iterable) {
    E prevValue = null;
    for (Iterator<E> iter = iterable.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        E value = iter.next();
        if (value.equals(prevValue))
            iter.remove();
        else
            prevValue = value;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A"));
removeRepeats(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

*Output*

`[A, B, A, C, A, B, A]`

Comment: The stateful predicate is, well... stateful. It works if the stream is sequential, but I think these kind of solutions shouldn't be encouraged. The loop solution fails if the list/iterable contains a null element in the first position, otherwise it's fine. Finally, I upvoted due to the collector-based solution, which should be common knowledge among java developers by 2018.

Comment: @Andrew Option 3 performs best, so use that if you can, otherwise option 2. As I already said in the answer, don't use option 1, but I included it because it is a common suggestion for your kind of problem, even though it's a bad suggestion.

Comment: Thank You. For me best readable is solution with implements `Predicate` morethan is short, and clean. Yes this broken some rule, as You wrote, but in this situation a buy it, because for me the most important is readable.

Comment: You only have to be aware that your stateful predicate may break with a parallel stream, as well as in a `flatMap` context and perhaps some more situations…

Comment: @Andreas - for the 1st object, we have prevValue = null. Why does Predicate.test(T t) not throw an exception for the 1st object since it has a null prevValue?

Comment: @armani Because the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) say it's not allowed to throw NPE: *For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.*

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple without using streams.. Something like this:

```
public List<T> noConsecutiveDuplicates(final List<T> input) {   
    final List<T> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final T element : input) {
        if (!element.equals(lastElement(output))) {
            output.add(element);
        }
    }
    return output;
}    

private T lastElement(final List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return list.get(list.size() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would give `StreamEx` a shot and use `StreamEx::collapse`:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A");

List<String> collect = StreamEx.of(strings)
        .collapse(Objects::equals)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is also possible by using vanilla Java and utilize the idea of ["edge detection"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35247952/4105457):

```
List<String> collect = IntStream.range(0, strings.size())
        .filter(i -> i == 0 || !Objects.equals(strings.get(i - 1), strings.get(i)))
        .mapToObj(strings::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A");
       List<String> result = IntStream.range(0, lst.size())
      .filter(index->index ==0 || !lst.get(index).equals(lst.get(index-1)))
      .mapToObj(i->lst.get(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());

result.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
```

You can simply iterate over the indexes from the source of the data and filter those elements which are not same as previous element.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cleanest solution, but you could use a filter, that remembers previous stream value.

```
class noDuplicateFilter implementsd Function<T>{
    private T previous=null;

    public boolean test(T input){

       boolean distinct= !Objects.equals(input, previous);
       this.previous = input;
       return distinct;
    }
}
```

Then use it inside of your stream.

Probably there is a bleaner solutino in JavaRx.

There are also some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8)

Comment: I want a "bleaner solutino" too :-)

Comment: It's not clean since it'll *fail* if the stream is parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most concise way is to use the reduce method as below;

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> ss =Arrays.asList("A","A","A","B","B", "A","A","A", "C", "C", "C","A","A","B","B","A");
        BiFunction<ArrayList<String>, String, ArrayList<String>> acc = new BiFunction<ArrayList<String>, String, ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<String> apply(ArrayList<String> strings, String s) {
                if(strings.isEmpty() || !strings.get(strings.size()-1).equals(s)){
                    strings.add(s);
                }
                return strings;
            }
        };
        BinaryOperator<ArrayList<String>> combiner = new BinaryOperator<ArrayList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ArrayList<String> apply(ArrayList<String> strings, ArrayList<String> strings2) {
                strings.addAll(strings2);
                return strings;
            }
        };
        ss.stream().reduce(new ArrayList<String>(), acc, combiner).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: The combiner is wrong. You should only combine the lists if the first element of the right list is not equal to the last element of the left list, else you should add the sublist of right that starts at its second element. (You should also check for emptiness of both lists). Besides, why aren't you using lambdas instead of anonymous inner classes?

Comment: Yes you are right with all your comments, i just wanted to introduce another way, with causual coding, the point about combiner os that ot will never be used in this case, however in order to make our code clean it should be fixed as you said