# stream collect accumulator/combiner order

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is basically a follow-up of [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173388/1059372).

Suppose that I am working on custom collector and supposing that the `accumulator` *always* will add some element to the collection returned by the supplier, is there any chance that when `combiner` is called, one of the intermediate results will be empty? An example is probably a lot simpler to understand.

Suppose I have a `List` of numbers and I want to split it in List of Lists, where `2` is the separator. So for example I have `1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8`, the result should be `[[1], [3, 4], [8]]`. This is not really complicated to achieve (don't judge the code too much, I wrote something fast, just so I could write this question).

```
List<List<Integer>> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8)
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    () -> new ArrayList<>(),
                    (list, elem) -> {
                        if (list.isEmpty()) {
                            List<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<>();
                            inner.add(elem);
                            list.add(inner);
                        } else {
                            if (elem == 2) {
                                list.add(new ArrayList<>());
                            } else {
                                List<Integer> last = list.get(list.size() - 1);
                                last.add(elem);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    (left, right) -> {
                        // This is the real question here:
                        // can left or right be empty here?
                        return left;
                    }));
```

This is irrelevant probably in this example, but the question is: can the one the elements in the `combiner` be an empty `List`? I am really really inclined to say `NO`, since in the documentation these are referred as:

> combiner - an associative, non-interfering, stateless function that accepts **two partial result containers** and merges them.

Well that *partial* to me is an indication that `accumulator` was called on them, before they reached `combiner`, but just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no guaranty that the accumulator has been applied to a container before merging. In other words, the lists to merge may be empty.

To demonstrate this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).parallel().boxed()
         .filter(i -> i >= 3 && i < 7)
         .collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, (l1,l2)->{
             System.out.println(l1.size()+" + "+l2.size());
             l1.addAll(l2);
         });
```

On my machine, it prints:

```
0 + 0
0 + 0
0 + 0
1 + 1
0 + 2
0 + 2
1 + 1
2 + 0
2 + 2
```

The workload splitting happens at the source list, when the outcome of the filter operation is not known yet. Each chunk is processed the same way, without rechecking whether any element has arrived the accumulator.

Mind that starting with Java 9, you can also do something like

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).parallel().boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.filtering(i -> i >= 3 && i < 7, Collectors.toList()));
```

which is another reason why a collector (here, the `toList()` collector) should be prepared to encounter empty containers, as the filtering happens outside the `Stream` implementation and an `accept` call on the compound collector’s accumulator doesn’t always imply an `accept` call on the downstream collector’s accumulator.

The requirement of being able to handle empty containers is specified in the [`Collector` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collector.html):

> To ensure that sequential and parallel executions produce equivalent results, the collector functions must satisfy an *identity* and an [associativity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity) constraints.
>
> The identity constraint says that for any partially accumulated result, combining it with an empty result container must produce an equivalent result. That is, for a partially accumulated result `a` that is the result of any series of accumulator and combiner invocations, `a` must be equivalent to `combiner.apply(a, supplier.get())`.

Comment: Further reading: [Visualization of Java Stream parallelization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34381805/2711488).